# frollsum, frollapply, etc... alternative: frollmedian?

Tags: r, data.table

i am using frollsum with adaptive = TRUE to calculate the rolling sum over a window of 26 weeks, but for weeks < 26, the window is exactly the size of available weeks.

Is there anything similar, but instead of a rolling sum, a function to identify the most common value? I basically need the media of the past 26 (or less) weeks. I realize, that frollapply does not allow adaptive = TRUE, so that it is not working in my case, as I need values for the weeks before week 26 as well.

Here is an example (I added "desired" column four)

```
     week product sales  desired
  1:    1       1     8        8
  2:    2       1     8        8
  3:    3       1     7        8
  4:    4       1     4        8
  5:    5       1     7      7.5
  6:    6       1     4      7.5
  7:    7       1     8        8
  8:    8       1     9      and
  9:    9       1     4       so
 10:   10       1     7       on
 11:   11       1     5      ...
 12:   12       1     3
 13:   13       1     8
 14:   14       1    10
```

Here is some example code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)

week <- seq(1:100)
products <- seq(1:10)
sales <- round(runif(1000,1,10),0)

data <- as.data.table(cbind(merge(week,products,all=T),sales))
names(data) <- c("week","product","sales")

data[,desired:=frollapply(sales,26,median,adaptive=TRUE)] #This only starts at week 26
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `RcppRoll` with `data.table`:

```
library(RcppRoll)
data[, med_sales := 
    fifelse(is.na(x <- roll_medianr(sales, 26L)),
        c(sapply(1L:25L, function(n) median(sales[1L:n])), rep(NA, .N - 25L)),
        x)]
```

or using `replace` instead of `fifelse`:

```
data[, med_sales := replace(roll_medianr(sales, 26L), 1L:25L, 
    sapply(1L:25L, function(n) median(sales[1L:n])))]
```

output:

```
      week product sales med_sales
   1:    1       1     9         9
   2:    2       1     3         6
   3:    3       1     4         4
   4:    4       1     6         5
   5:    5       1     9         6
  ---                             
 996:   96      10     2         5
 997:   97      10     8         5
 998:   98      10     7         5
 999:   99      10     4         5
1000:  100      10     3         5
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
week <- seq(1:100)
products <- seq(1:10)
sales <- round(runif(1000,1,10),0)

data <- as.data.table(cbind(merge(week,products,all=T),sales))
names(data) <- c("week","product","sales")
```